# Reorder/group different elements in the DOM in order to wrap the similar ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this pattern that I have to change with jQuery:

```
    <li class="ref">
        <a href="#title1">title1</a>
    </li>
    <div id="title1" class="content"></div>
    <li class="ref">
        <a href="#title2">title2</a>
    </li>
    <div id="title2" class="content"></div>
```

I need it to become:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="ref">
        <a href="#title1">title1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ref">
        <a href="#title2">title2</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
<div>
    <div id="title1" class="content"></div>
    <div id="title2" class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I know I can wrap in the end both the group of li's and div's but I would appreciate a simple way to achieve this grouping of all of them in the DOM to replace them in a correct order.

Comment: I would suggest doing this in the source, not jQuery, as what you have initially is invalid, and will mess up the layout of the `ul`. Fixing the elements after the DOM has loaded will still leave the page invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I would like my code to be clean, could you tell me what tool gives an invalid error to this code? The answers below fixed my issues and my console shows no error.

Comment: Your console won't show an error, however the page will be rendered in quirks mode, and not standards. This can lead to issue with javascript, especially in IE. You should be able to tell the renderer being used in the DOM part of the console, or by using the w3c validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `wrapAll()` to wrap the selector

```
 $('.ref').wrapAll('<ul>');
 $('.content').wrapAll('<div>');
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/fXL6M/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This should help ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWyy9/)):

```
var ul = $('<ul>'), div = $('<div>'), body = $('body')
$('.ref').appendTo(ul)
$('.content').appendTo(div)
ul.add(div).appendTo(body)
```

Comment: Thank you krasu, bipen's answer is simpler so I'll go for that. I'll vote everyone up when I have more rep.